# Create custom User with OAuth2 data from authorization with Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to support both form login and Facebook authentication in my app, the goal is both to create a `User` object. With `formLogin` I can make a sign up controller and persist my User entity, but how can I intercept the OAuth2 authentication from Facebook to create (or login if it already exists) a User entity?

This is my security configuration so far:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth2/**", "/webjars/**", "/users/signup", "/users/recover", "/users/reset/**", "/img/**", "/css/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/users/login")
                .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler())
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/users/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/users/login?logout")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .oauth2Login()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("users/facebook");
    }
```

Is there a way to create a `successHandler` or similar to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution, as mentioned [here](https://medium.com/@bvulaj/mapping-your-users-and-roles-with-spring-boot-oauth2-a7ac3bbe8e7f) you should configure your OAuth2 authorization with the `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure` package using the `@ EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation and then creating a [PrincipalExtractor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/PrincipalExtractor.html) to build your User entity based on the data sent by the OAuth2 provider.

This way your own model object will be accesible through `getPrincipal()` in further calls.